# How to move xml file from local system to Docker

Tags: .net, xml, docker

I have xml files which is going to be input for web api. The web api return the response from xml.

The response returns null. I read about the issue and found the xml might not be mounted to the container so that is the issue why the xml is not returning.

so now I want to move my TokenData.xml into container. But I tried the below by

```
COPY ["aspnetcore-server/src/IO.Swagger/Operations/XMLMockData/TokenData.xml",  "aspnetcore-server/src/IO.Swagger/Operations/XMLMockData/"]
```

so in docker file I put the above code. I believed this will move my file from local to container. But it doesn't do anything to resolve the issue

I tried the below docker copy command. But it throws the "No such directory"

```
docker cp C:\Users\Ramji.R\Downloads\ThycoticCurrentone\Thycotic\ThycoticWrapperAPI\aspnetcore-server\src\IO.Swagger\Operations\XMLMockData\TokenData.xml thycoticwrapperapi_io.swagger_1:aspnetcore-server/src/IO.Swagger/Operations/XMLMockData/
```

Dockerfile :

```
#See https://aka.ms/containerfastmode to understand how Visual Studio uses this Dockerfile to build your images for faster debugging.

#Depending on the operating system of the host machines(s) that will build or run the containers, the image specified in the FROM statement may need to be changed.
#For more information, please see https://aka.ms/containercompat

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.0-nanoserver-1903 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.0-nanoserver-1903 AS build
WORKDIR /src

COPY ["aspnetcore-server/src/IO.Swagger/Operations/XMLMockData/TokenData.xml",  "aspnetcore-server/src/IO.Swagger/Operations/XMLMockData/"]

COPY ["aspnetcore-server/src/IO.Swagger/IO.Swagger.csproj", "aspnetcore-server/src/IO.Swagger/"]
RUN dotnet restore "aspnetcore-server/src/IO.Swagger/IO.Swagger.csproj"
COPY . .



WORKDIR "/src/aspnetcore-server/src/IO.Swagger"
RUN dotnet build "IO.Swagger.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "IO.Swagger.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "IO.Swagger.dll"]
```

Docker-compose.yml :

```
version: '3.4'

    services:
      io.swagger:
        image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}ioswagger
        build:
          context: .
          dockerfile: aspnetcore-server\src\IO.Swagger\Dockerfile
```

Let me know how to move the xml into container. Also how I can view whether the container have the file once it is moved. Any command to check that?

Comment: For anyone searching to try to solve a similar issue: The source XML file name in my scenario had a casing mismatch, and this was not apparent as Visual Studio did not care.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are leaving your xml file behind inside the build image. What you need to do is copy this in your final image.

```
COPY --from=build/IO.Swagger/Operations/XMLMockData/TokenData.xml /XMLMockData
```

You might have to change the target destination of the copy depending on where this has to be relative to your dll. You can also inspect the content of the final image by running:

```
 docker exec [OPTIONS] CONTAINER COMMAND [ARG...]
```

Comment: copy --from-build \Operations\XMLMockData\TokenData.xml aspnetcore-server/src/IO.Swagger/Operations/XMLMockData i tried the above command but it seems like the file path is not correct I'm getting the file not found. Whether the given answer should be a part of docker file?

Comment: I updated the copy. There was a syntax error. Its from=build. Also, if that doesn't work, try adding the full path ; aspnetcore-server/src/IO.Swagger/Operations/XMLMockData/TokenData.xml

Comment: @alan Thanks for providing the answer. Your answer helped as hint to solve the issue.